# problem with scrollTop

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I have the following markup:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;width:500px;height:100px;">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Mow I'm adding a new listitem with jQuery. How can I make it visible (scrolling the div to it) in case it's hidden?

I've tried `UL.scrollTop(nuLI.top);` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `scrollTop()` on the element with the overflow, which is the `<div>` element, not the `<ul>` element. Further you need to grab the `top` by [`element.position().top`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and you need to ensure that the `<div>` element is positioned relatively using `position: relative`, since the `top` is relative to the firstnext relative parent element.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2621792</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#div').scrollTop($('#li3').position().top);
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #div {
                position: relative;
                overflow: auto;
                width: 100px;
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li id="li3">Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried @BalusC method, but the scroll will bounce back if it has already reached the bottom. Then I figured out, by inserting ".scrollTop(0)" before the actual scrollTop will maintain the scroll position.

`$('#div').scrollTop(0).scrollTop($('#li3').position().top);`